# SQL insert in case statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a syntax issue near the inner insert.

The error message:

> Incorrect syntax near 'INSERT'

(and marked below in commented section). Does anyone know a way to insert into a table within a case statement and then select the scope identity?

```
INSERT
INTO dbo.WorkOrderMasterLabor ( WorkOrderMasterID , TaskID , ContractorLaborCraftID , EmployeeLaborCraftID , Sequence , ModifiedTimestamp , ModifiedUserName )
SELECT
        (SELECT WorkOrderMasterID FROM WorkOrderMasters WHERE JobNumber = A.JOBNO),
        NULL,
        NULL,
        CASE WHEN EXISTS(
                SELECT 1
                FROM dbo.EmployeeLaborCrafts 
                WHERE EmployeeID = (
                    SELECT EmployeeID
                    FROM Employees
                    WHERE EmployeeNumber = A.EMPLOYEENO
                )
                AND LaborCraftID = (
                    SELECT LaborCraftID
                    FROM LaborCrafts
                    WHERE LaborCraftCode = A.LABORCODE
                )
            ) 
            THEN (
                SELECT EmployeeLaborCraftID
                FROM dbo.EmployeeLaborCrafts 
                WHERE EmployeeID = (
                    SELECT EmployeeID
                    FROM Employees
                    WHERE EmployeeNumber = A.EMPLOYEENO
                )
                AND LaborCraftID = (
                    SELECT LaborCraftID
                    FROM LaborCrafts
                    WHERE LaborCraftCode = A.LABORCODE
                )
            )
            ELSE (
                --syntax error at insert
                INSERT
                INTO dbo.EmployeeLaborCrafts ( EmployeeID , LaborCraftID , ModifiedTimestamp , ModifiedUserName )
                SELECT *
                FROM @PMMLABOR
                SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()
            ) 
        END,
        '',
        GETDATE(),
        N'Administrator'
FROM @PMMLABOR A
```

Comment: You can't have an insert statement inside your else clause of your case statement

Comment: Aside from fact that `case` is expression not a statement in SQL Server and can't be used for control flow  - how to you suppose this: `insert into ... select case when something then select ... else insert...` should work?

Comment: If you are trying to catch errors using a case statement you would probably be better off using `TRY` and `CATCH`

Comment: OK, good to know. I will have to find another way around this problem. Thanks

Comment: Remember that your case statement is just part of the `INSERT INTO SELECT [...]`.  You can use subqueries to provide for your SELECT, but as far as I know, you'll have to make a separate insert statement.  You should put your logic into a View or preferably a stored procedure and then call that instead of trying to do it all at once with a single statement.

Comment: also, since you only have 1 condition for your else statement, and if it doesn't fit that condition, then you need to specify the value FOR THAT COLUMN). Now if there's really only one way that that data should be, then remove the case statement altogether, and throw a try/catch around the whole insert/select blob to catch the condition when it DOESN'T meet your original rules of your case when statement. Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a re-written version where it will only insert the values when it meets your case when clause:

```
INSERT
INTO dbo.WorkOrderMasterLabor ( WorkOrderMasterID , TaskID , ContractorLaborCraftID , EmployeeLaborCraftID , Sequence , ModifiedTimestamp , ModifiedUserName )
SELECT
        (SELECT WorkOrderMasterID FROM WorkOrderMasters WHERE JobNumber = A.JOBNO),
        NULL,
        NULL,
        (
            SELECT EmployeeLaborCraftID
            FROM dbo.EmployeeLaborCrafts 
            WHERE EmployeeID = (
                SELECT EmployeeID
                FROM Employees
                WHERE EmployeeNumber = A.EMPLOYEENO
            )
            AND LaborCraftID = (
                SELECT LaborCraftID
                FROM LaborCrafts
                WHERE LaborCraftCode = A.LABORCODE
            )
        ),
        '',
        GETDATE(),
        N'Administrator'
FROM @PMMLABOR A
where   EXISTS(
                SELECT 1
                FROM dbo.EmployeeLaborCrafts 
                WHERE EmployeeID = (
                    SELECT EmployeeID
                    FROM Employees
                    WHERE EmployeeNumber = A.EMPLOYEENO
                )
                AND LaborCraftID = (
                    SELECT LaborCraftID
                    FROM LaborCrafts
                    WHERE LaborCraftCode = A.LABORCODE
                )
            )
```

You could run this same select statement, doing a `NOT EXISTS` instead to find the ones that would fail, then you could raise an exception based on that result.